# telegram bot split keyboard rows[columns]

Tags: php, arrays, bots, telegram

I am writing my telegram bot codes in PHP. I would like to split my inline keyboard into 2 or 3 columns. Here is my code:

```
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    $key[] = array(
        array('text'=>$cat['name'],'callback_data'=>'sub-'.$cat['id'])
    );

    if ($k % 2 == 0) {
        $keyoptions[] = $key;
        $key = array();   
    }

    $k++;
}
$telegram->SendMessage($userid, $keyoptions);
```

but my code doesn't work. Where is the problem and how can I solve my issue?

EDIT :

i just used this code

```
$keyoptions = array_chunk($keyoptions,3);
```

but still can't find the problem;

Answer (score 1):

[Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup): inline_keyboard: Array of Array of InlineKeyboardButton

**Example:**

```
keyboard: [
["uno :+1:"],["uno \ud83d\udc4d", "due"],["uno", "due","tre"]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what library you are using and what are those fields in your code, but this a working with native telegram API:

```
function inlineKeyboard($text, $chatID, $btnNames, $callBackDatas)
{
    $inlineRow = array(); // this is array for each row of buttons
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($btnNames as $name) {
        array_push($inlineRow, array("text" => $name, "callback_data" => $callBackDatas[$i]));
        $i++;
    }
    /* if you need multiple rows then just create other inlineRow arrays
       and push to this array below */
    $inlineKeyboard = array($inlineRow);

    $keyboard = array(
        "inline_keyboard" => $inlineKeyboard
    );
    $postfields = array
    (
        'chat_id' => "$chatID",
        'text' => $text,
        'reply_markup' => json_encode($keyboard)
    );

    send('sendMessage', $postfields);

}


define('BaseURL', 'https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>');
function send($method, $datas)
{
    $url = BaseURL . "/" . $method;

    if (!$curld = curl_init()) {
        exit;
    }
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datas);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($curld);
    curl_close($curld);
    return $output;
}
```